# JQuery Image Uploading and Cropping

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck on the image cropping.. Is there any way to crop image using javascript/jquery only.. I don't want any language like PHP or any.. I want to perform Image uploading and cropping using javascript/jquery only. Any one help me...? Is there any examples demos available?

Comment: if the user has chrome firefox etc you can use canvas, but ie doesnt support canvas, or at least the old ones dont, seems 9,10 do and 11 will http://caniuse.com/canvas

Comment: For cropping there are already a few answers but you cannot upload an image with jQuery only.

Comment: @putvande yes, you CAN upload an image with jquery only.  No need to use XHR directly.

Comment: @putvande, you can if you use canvas, canvas has a toDataUrl which outputs a base64 encoded image, which you can then send to the server.

Comment: Send to the server. But you need a bit of server side script to upload right?

Comment: @putvande yes, that's correct.  My guess is you are addressing the OP's request to exclude PHP.  I think the OP is simply asking for a client side only solution as far as cropping is concerned, but its not clear.  I'm not even sure the OP knows what a server is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jcrop plugin for this : http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html